# Import TypeScript variable in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, global-variables

I am trying to style (styled-components) a fabric js component (Dropdown) as a react component.

The css class names are declared in a file office-ui-fabric-react/lib/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.scss.d.ts. Example:

```
export declare const root = "root_15a7b352";
```

I want to import this class name so I can use it in styled.

AFAIK this is TypeScript global variable and I tried looking for information on how to get to it but with no success.

Comment: Why do you want to import this specific class? You can refer to `Dropdown` and use classes inside it with `styled-components`

Comment: Tell me more please (I am kinda new to this) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `declare const root` is not the same as `const root`. It means:

> There is a variable called *root* somewhere else, and I'm just here to describe it.

In other words, it tells us something on the type level, but it doesn't contain any executable code. It's not possible to consume it in runtime. You can verify it by inspecting the generated code in [TypeScript playground](https://agentcooper.github.io/typescript-play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDsiA7AZ3iggngF44AiEsgfQEYBWdAdgCMBmJgJioG4AUEA).

Most likely it's meant to be imported from someplace else, or is, in fact, a global variable Since the declaration file describes `Dropdown.scss`, it's likely that `root` is a CSS class living in that file. Try:

```
import { root } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.scss'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Karol Majeswski's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697806/4374566) gets it right on importing the variable from typescript.

However, it seems your intention is to style parts of the dropdown using `styled-components`, instead of importing this variable from scss file, the Dropdown component provides readable classnames like `ms-Dropdown-title` that can be used for styling.

For eg. to style the Dropdown, you would use:

```
const StyledDropdown = styled(Dropdown)`
  color: red;

  & .ms-Dropdown-title {
    background-color: red;
  }
`;
```

[See Codepen example](https://codepen.io/BoyWithSilverWings/pen/JwjrOV?editors=0010)

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. However there are class names like "root_15a7b352" which are compiled/transpilated/generated somehow and I need them. So I need to import the name otherwise on new fabric-js version the id after the underscore might be different and my styled will not work.